# How to dump a string file and save it as a HTML document?

Tags: php, html

I have a script that looks like this.

```
$html = <<<__END__
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>

</head>
{$body}

</body>
</html>
__END__;
```

what would be the proper way to save this script output as a HTML file.

for example.

I wanna be able to go like this.

save_to_html($html,'directory/filename)'

and when I go to directory, I will be able to find the html file with contents from the variable above.

Comment: You want this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I know it was an easy one for some of you, but there is no need to vote down someone question even though it might had been very easy for some.. nonetheless, please know there is no such thing as a stupid question and everyone is at a different level in their journey with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function save_to_html($html, $path)
{
    $f = fopen($path, 'w');
    if (file_put_contents($path, $html) === false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Example of use:

```
save_to_html($html, 'directory/newfile.html');
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) so you would use

```
include('your_file.php');
file_put_contents('directory/filename',$html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the buffer with `ob_start` & `ob_get_contents`

see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-get-contents.php

```
ob_start();

echo $html =' <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>

</head>
{$body}

</body>
</html>';

    $file_name='cache.txt';
if($fopen=@fopen(PATH.$file_name, 'a')){
         fwrite($fopen, ob_get_contents());
     fclose($fopen);
}

ob_end_flush();

ob_flush();

flush();
```

Use `echo` to put your content in the buffer and `ob_get_content`s to get the content from the buffer. Then save in a file.